# How can I install ubuntu on virtual box with just command prompt

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox

My laptop does not a lot of RAM. I have installed Virtual box on my windows 7 machine.
How can I install a Ubuntu environment with just console?

Thank you.

Comment: ubuntu server is console only :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download from ubuntu.com the **ubuntu server 12.04 LTS .iso** image (for server always use **the latest LTS** edition).
2. Create a new VM machine (512 MB RAM)
3. In storage settings change empty DVD with the .iso (first boot)
4. start the vm machine. (it will boot from .iso)
5. Follow the Ubuntu server installation instructions.

**ubuntu server and windows environment**

first in ubuntu server run:

```
sudo tasksel
```

and choose for install **openssh and samba server**

on windows

download and install **putty** and **winscp**

**with putty** you can manage ubuntu server through windows and

**with winscp** you can copy delete etc ubuntu server files and directories

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have done that. But now how can I configure my ubuntu server environment so that I can copy from my Host (Windows 7) to my ubuntu server environment runs on Virtual box?

Comment: see the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

complete virtuabox tutorial here :

http://cheznick.net/main/content/creating-a-virtual-machine-using-the-virtualbox-cli

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-control-virtual-machines-virtualbox-using-vboxmanage.html